# How to connect to my remote Mysql Database via Xampp

Tags: php, xampp

I am using Xampp to update my website and since I have added a Mysql database I have the error further down locally while it works fine online.

I'm using the code below to connect to my database:

```
<?php
$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

http://localhost/connectdb.php

Result:

> Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No
>   such host is known.

http://example.com/connectdb.php

Result:

> Connected successfully

So there must be some configuration to do in Xampp to access a remote database or do I need to ask my host to whitelist my private IP Address? My host is OVH.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It should work. Try to connect to it via another db manager, like HeidiSQL. Perhaps this provider doesn't allow remote access.

Comment: Give Server name as "localhost"

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have changed the server name to "localhost" and I have the following error: Connection failed: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

Comment: Got it, this works fine - thanks for your time everyone: $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

Comment: But now I have the following error: Unknown database 'mydatabase' I guess I've just managed to connect to local Mysql but not to my remote database...so I'm back to my initial question.